# Data is not validating in formset django. Error "The NameOfModel could not be created because the data didn't validate."

Tags: python, django, formset

I'm building a formset but when I try to save the data appears the erros "The Fields could not be created because the data didn't validate."

My forms.py

```
class Formulario(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fields
        fields = ['name','type']

FieldsFormSet = formset_factory(Formulario)
```

My views.py

```
class BuildForm(CreateView):
    template_name = 'formulario.html'
    model = Fields
    form_class = Formulario
    success_url = 'success/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        fields_form = FieldsFormSet(self.request.POST,self.request.FILES)
        if fields_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, fields_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, fields_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, fields_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        fields_form.instance = self.object
        fields_form.save()

    def form_invalid(self, form, fields_form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,fields_form=fields_form))
```

template.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="section">
    </div>
    <h2>Todo Items</h2>
    {{ fields_form.management_form }}
    {% for form in fields_form.forms %}
    <div class="item">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <p style=""><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><a id="add" href="#">Add another item</a></p>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
</form>
```

Weird is, it does validate until form_valid()

Comment: use if form.is_valid(): instead of if fields_form.is_valid():

Comment: @CodeIsLife thanks for your reply, but changing this, now pass to form_invalid()

Comment: did you tried to handle the validation error message ?

Comment: No, Im not handling validations error message yet because Im trying first validate if pass to form_valid(). It was validating form_valid() with fields_form.is_valid() but appears the error of the question, and how you said me not pass to form_invalid()

Comment: could you  "print formset.errors" just before if fields_form.is_valid():

Comment: I printed forms.errors not formset.errors and show this:

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>type<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>form<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

But im filling all the fields...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138434/discussion-between-codeislife-and-dfrojas).